How to send the redirectionURL back to sagepay using .NET Core
I'm using .NET 7 with nop commerce. I have created the notificationURL to return the status, statusDetail, and the redirectionURL. In opayo documentation, it asks to send back the redirectURL in to opayo.
How do I send the those details back to opayo?
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> WebhookHandler()
{
    // some implementation
    if (success)
    {
        return Ok(new { Status = "OK", RedirectURL = redirUrl });
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(new { Status = "ERROR", RedirectURL = redirUrl });
    }
}


LinkGenerator can generate absolute urls including the protocol and host; Url.Get[something](context, ..... scheme: context.Request.Scheme). Just provide a scheme or host parameter to force that behaviour.
